# Google Page insights user experience issue

Tags: google, page-speed, google-insights

When using the Google Page Insights I got a 84 / 100 for user experience.

It gives me the message to check my tab targets.

I got more then 10 messages saying that one target is to close to another one.

In my responsive design for mobile devices I have a hidden sidebar at the left and right that is behind my main content. After swiping to a side a sidebar is shown because of the main content is moved to the left or right.

So all of the targets from these messages are from the sidebars.

Should I pay attention to this or not?

Comment: Google uses the scoring from that tool to influence search engine rankings for mobile.   I don't recall what the cutoff is, but you don't want a low score or Google won't show your site in the mobile results.

Comment: Yes I know but how can I solve it in my situation? I think many other developers are using the same technic by adding sidebars that are shown when you swipe to the left or right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ones that are interested, I solved it by setting a `display: none;` on both sidebars ( even when they are overlayed by the main content container ).

Then while swiping, set display to block.

Now the score is 99!

Comment: I hate that Google uses broken modeling to make decisions about how good or bad your website is.   At least in this case they have made a tool that webmasters can use to score their own websites.  For most of Google's algorithms we have no insight into the bad decisions their code is making against our sites.